# Get the sender address in ContractB when called from ContractA

Tags: solidity, msg.sender

I have 2 contracts **A** & **B**. **A** calls one of the methods from **B**.

How do I get the caller address in that method of **B**? Usually `msg.sender` in **A** will give the address of caller but we cannot do the same in **B** since it is called from **A** and in doing so we get the **A** address not the caller address.

So what is way of getting the actual caller address in **B** without passing it as method params from **A**?

Answer (score 0):

There are few ways to handle this.

First, think about the security model for `B`. In many cases, it will be captive by `A` - i.e. only should be talking to it, in that case, `A` can be said to be "trusted". But, if anyone/anything can call `B` then `A` is "untrusted".

Method 1

`tx.origin` is meant to present the data you want, but security concerns mean it is seldom used. The security concern is an "untrusted" `A` can manipulate it to mislead `B` - not good. IIRC, there has been some development around this param. Possibly a kind soul can chime in with it's current status. The second method is more common.

Method 2

Pass it through from `A` to `B`. This is the most idiomatic method but it relies on a trust relationship between `A` and `B` ... `B` simply relies on `A`'s statement about it. Very secure as long as `A` is trustworthy.

```
contract A {

 ...

   bool response = B(address).doSomething(msg.sender);
 ...

contract B {

   function doSomething(address sender) public onlyTrustedSender {returns bool) {
     ...
```

Notice that `B`'s function is guarded so it only accepts the `sender` parameter from parties that it trusts. This is secure provided there is no opening for a sender to send false information.

Hope it helps.

Comment: I kinda follow the second approach where A can be always the trustworthy. But method in B can be called by anyone as long as it is public or external passing any sender address as method params. This leans me to think about more on security issues when somebody directly invokes method from B

Comment: That's why you have to guard it with access control. Here, the `onlyTrustedSender` modifier is responsible to ensuring only trusted `msg.sender` (however you define that) gets through.